# DBPedia Person dataset

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I need to extract Person's names with variation from DBPEdia.
 My SPARQL request:

```
   select distinct ?o where {
    { ?instance <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>; 
     <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> ?o }
     union
       {
         ?instance <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>; 
         rdfs:label
       }
   FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),"en"))}
```

DBPedia returns only 50 000 names via SRARQL request.

May be a dataset exists for Persons with all names variation?

Existing persons_en.nt dataset contains only foaf:name but I need other names' variations. Sometimes they listed in rdfs:label(e.g. for Maria Sharapova).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in another post. Run the following SPARQL:

```
SELECT ?o WHERE {  
{
  select distinct ?o 
     where {
             ?instance <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>; 
             rdfs:label ?o  
            FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),"en"))
           } 
    ORDER BY ASC(?o)
  }
 } OFFSET 800000 LIMIT 50000
```

in the Java programm:

```
  Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
  QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
```